# Constrained maximization of ....

Tags: optimization, economics, constraints, utility

I have to maximize $U(x,y)= Min(ax+y, by+x)$ s.a $p_{1}x +p_{2}y =m$. I try the traditional solution for a leontieff $(ax_{1}+y= by_{1}+x)$ function but I'm not sure.. beacause exist regions where one plan is under the other and only one of them is a minimun...

Comment: So $ax_1$ and $by_1$ are constants ?

Comment: only $a$ and $b$

Answer (score 0):

I do not think an analytical solution exists for the problem.

For a numerical solution, you can use the simplex algorithm to solve the problem, once you have linearized it as follows:
$$
\mbox{Maximize }\; Z= t
$$
subject to
$$
ax+y\ge t\\
by+x\ge t\\
p_1x+p_2y=m
$$

Answer (score 0):

It seems if you solve the system of equations
[ p1x+p2y=m; ax+y=by+x]
you get exactly the solution.

Comment: A full answer would *do* what you've suggested...